Change colors displayed in LyX
I find for example green too bright:

How can I change the color displayed in LyX (but not in the output file) to something else?
LyX Version 2.4.1 (Monday, July 1, 2024)
Windows:


+1 Nice question, by the way. I especially appreciate that you added a screenshot and that you specified "not in the output file". That makes your question very clear! One minor comment: it's always useful to put your OS and LyX version. For example, in the recently released LyX 2.4 some things regarding colors have changed.

I'm sorry I misunderstood your question. I deleted my (non) answer. I didn't realize that you are talking about when you manually set the text color to green. Thanks for your patience to my misunderstanding. I'm glad you figured out an answer and thanks for sharing it here!


In LyX, go to Help > About LyX > Version, open the User Directory.
There should be a file "preferences". Open it with any text editor. Under # COLOR SECTION ###################################, enter in an additional line \set_color "green" "#008000". This will change the displayed green color to RGB = 008000 (darker green).
Save "preferences" file.
In LyX, go to Tools > click "Reconfigure".
Restart LyX.

(Credit to this answer by Udi Fogiel.)
